# Using r2dbc-postgresql for CockroachDB result in authentication failure: "Password must not be null"

Tags: spring-webflux, kotlin-coroutines, cockroachdb, r2dbc-postgresql

I'm trying to connect to a CockroachDB cluster using r2dbc-postgresql, (I've tried both org.postgresql as well as io.r2dbc) as well as spring-data-r2dbc from my reactive Kotlin app - which is running on spring webflux. When attempting to connect, It fails to authenticate first because the selected connection strategy is SingleHostConnection which uses username and password. I thought it'd fall back to SSL after but it throws an error and discards. Any idea how to trigger SSL connection explicitly? OR does r2dbc require strictly UsernameAndPassword authentication?

When I was debugging, I noticed that it was using ReactorNettyClient.connect method as its default connection function but once SingleHostConnectionFunction's connect method started executing, it never hit. Seems like that's where it needs to go.